# How do I navigate to a different page from a command class

Tags: .net, xaml, win-universal-app

So I have a sign-in page that has a single button. When you click the button, a command fires which takes the username and password and goes off to get an auth token. What I am trying to figure out is how to deal with the results of the command. For instance, if it fails, I want to display a dialog, but if it succeeds, I want it to navigate to a different page.

Where I'm getting confused is where I can get a reference to the page so that I can either open that dialog or navigate away. The command class has a reference to the view model, but my view model is declared in the XAML, not in the code-behind. Or maybe bind the CommandParameter to an instance of the view somehow?

Am I going about this wrong; does this sound smelly? I'm relatively new to XAML so I don't know what the norms are. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean using MVVM? or standard event oriented?

Comment: MVVM. I'm trying to avoid the code-behind completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Navigation using MVVM is usually the most complex part, what I recommend

1.- A Views enum with the name of the Views (MainView, DetailsView)

```
public enum AppViews
{
    MainView,
    DetailsView
}
```

2.- An interface called INavigation that contains a method Navigate(Views view)

```
public interface INavigation
{
    void Navigate(AppViews view);
}
```

3.- A class that contains the Current INavigation instance as static:

```
public class NavigationLocator
{
    static INavigation Current { get; set; }
}
```

(That depends on how is your ViewModel, PCL, windows, etc defined)

4.- In the App class implement INavigation:

```
 public void Navigate(AppViews view)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType("ProjectName." + view.ToString());

        rootFrame.Navigate(type, null);
    }
```

5.- In the App Constructor

```
  public App()
  {
     NavigationLocator.Current = this;
  }
```

6.- Call in your MVVM

```
NavigationLocator.Current.Navigate(AppViews.DetailsView);
```

and that's it.

Comment: How is this any different than just calling the Navigate method on Window.Current.Content? Or did I just answer my own question?

Comment: In that case you are not using pure MVVM because you are using the Window class, not abstracting it with an interface, (imagine another platform that instead of Window class could be Activity class) the ViewModel will be the same and only the View part changes

Comment: root frame doesn't appear to be accessible in App.cs so i basically have to do what I said earlier (Window.Current.Content) to get the root frame -- and the biggest difference is that I'm abstracting it from the Command and using a locator. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes or simply extract it rootFrame instance in App.xaml.cs where it is instanced outside   Frame rootFrame; protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) { ... rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;} and you have it. it's the same